# Why does MATLAB plot the same thing twice, messing up a new plot?

Tags: matlab, debugging

I am using the MATLAB live editor and I have made a 2x5 plot showing the pole-zero maps and impulse response functions for several systems, as shown in the figure. I would then like to plot another function below it; the impulse of TF_feedback2. However, when I try to plot this latest figure, it plots the set of 2x5 plots again with the new function. Obviously i just want to have one plot there (actually I want a different set of 2x5, but reasoned that wont work if one figure wont work). How do I fix this?

Here is the image:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
for i = 1:5
    TF(i) = tf(N(i,:),D(i,:));
end

for i = 0:4
    subplot('position', [(0.05 + i*.18) .6 .15 .25])
    pzmap(TF(i+1))
    xlim([-5,5])
    if i ~= 0
        xlabel(' ','Fontsize',0.01)
        ylabel(' ','Fontsize',0.01)
        title(' ','Fontsize',0.01)
    else
        xlabel(' ','Fontsize',10)
        ylabel(' ','Fontsize',10)
    end
end

for i = 0:4
    subplot('position', [(0.05 + i*.18) .2 .15 .25])
    impulse(N(i+1,:),D(i+1,:), 0:0.01:4)
    xlim([0,4])
    if i ~= 0
        xlabel(' ','Fontsize',0.01)
        ylabel(' ','Fontsize',0.01)
        title(' ','Fontsize',0.01)
    else
        xlabel(' ','Fontsize',10)
        ylabel(' ','Fontsize',10)
    end
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PROBLEM 3%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

TF_feedback2 = feedback(TF(2),1);

impulse(TF_feedback2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why everything is getting plotted twice. However, it looks like you aren't defining a new plot for your last figure. The last subplot will remain active, and your final plot will overwrite that one. Try creating another subplot before your final figure and see if it helps with your problem.

Comment: Since you are creating a grid layout with the subplots, it is easier to use [`subplot`s](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) signature `subplot(m,n,p)`, which could look like `for i=0:4; subplot(2,5,i); pzmap(...), % ...`. This will also rescale, when you change the image dimensions later.